# How to convert advice to reported speech?

Tags: reported-speech

> On social media, you should only connect to people you know well.

How should the sentence be converted to reported speech? *He said that …*??

I know very well the rules of reported speech, yet this sentence has really confused me especially the verb "know". Do I have to follow the rules and make it "knew" or can I keep it as it is?? and why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's suppose Alice said *"You should only connect to people you know well"*, and Bob has to decide how to tell other people about this later. Bob needs to choose between saying...

> 1: *Alice said that you should only connect to people you **know** well.*
>    OR
>    2: *Alice said that you should only connect to people you **knew** well.*

Both versions are grammatically fine, but in terms of *nuanced meaning*, the use of Present Tense in #1 implies greater relevance to time of speaking (I mean when *Bob* is speaking, not Alice). That "greater relevance" would usually be understood to mean that Bob *endorses* what Alice said, and therefore wants ***you*** (whoever he's talking to) to take that advice on board ***now*** (it's "current").

Conversely, the use of Past Tense in #2 places the advice more firmly in the ***past*** (or in the ***hypothetical*** [irrealis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrealis_mood) of *If you knew him well you would like him*). That's more appropriate if Bob *doesn't* endorse Alice's advice, because he's introduced a greater "distance" (past => present) in the way he reports what was said.

Arguably one might also be more inclined to use Past Tense if we replace Alice by, say, ***Plato*** because the advice was obviously given a very long time ago. But to be honest, I'm not convinced that applies as a justification in and of itself.

Comment: While I agree with this, I think I would also use "know" when reporting very recent events even if I don't endorse the advice, e.g. "You won't believe what Alice said to me yesterday - she actually said that you should only connect with people you know well on social media." I think that I'd probably use that as long as I think nothing about the advice would have changed since Alice said it.

Comment: @Paul: Possibly. But when reporting very recent events, I think Bob would be much more likely to say *"Alice **says** that you should only connect to people you know well"* anyway. And once he's opted to report what she *says* rather than what she *said*, he pretty much has to stick with Present Tense throughout.